# MS Access: Calling VBA function in form event property (like On Dbl Click) - refers to object closed or doesn't exist

Tags: vba, function, ms-access

I have taken a macro that was embedded and converted it into vba so I can call it on different forms when needed. The form I am using is an employee list form and I am using it on the first name. I have tried calling the function by putting `=MyFunction()` and I get the object is closed or doesn't exist.

It works as an embedded macro; however, when I try to use it as a standalone I get an error and when I converted it I get the above error.

```
Function Copy_Of_CompID_Fields()
On Error GoTo Copy_Of_CompID_Fields_Err

    With CodeContextObject
        On Error Resume Next
        If (Eval("[Forms].[Dirty]")) Then
            DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
        End If
        If (.MacroError.Number <> 0) Then
            Beep
            MsgBox .MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
            Exit Function
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        If (IsNull(.New_Id)) Then
            Exit Function
        End If
        If (.CreatedDate < #5/1/2019#) Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Employee Details", acNormal, "", "[ID]='" & .ID & "'", , acNormal
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenForm "Employee Details", acNormal, "", "[New_Id]=" & .ID, , acNormal
        End If
        TempVars.Add "CurrentID", .ID
        DoCmd.Requery ""
        DoCmd.SearchForRecord , "", acFirst, "[ID]='" & TempVars!CurrentID & "'"
        TempVars.Remove "CurrentID"
    End With

Copy_Of_CompID_Fields_Exit:
    Exit Function

Copy_Of_CompID_Fields_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Copy_Of_CompID_Fields_Exit

End Function
```

Comment: Where the error appears?

Comment: Function is `Copy_Of_CompID_Fields()` not `MyFunction()`. If you are really using `=MyFunction()`, I expect it would fail.

Comment: `[Forms]` is a collection of forms, so how could this work?: `[Forms].[Dirty]`

Comment: @June7 I am not using MyFunction(). I only used that as an example to see if I was using the proper syntax in the property field.

Comment: Is the function in a module? If it is part of a form, that form would need to be open for you to call the function.

Comment: @unhandled That is exactly what my problem was with the standalone macro. I took the suggestion that popped up which had an "s" in it.

Comment: Best to use actual code when you have it, not example. Regarding Dirty property, review http://allenbrowne.com/bug-01.html.

Comment: Can you tell us which line of code produces the error?